# Pull-up and pull-down in USB differential line and logic levels

Tags: usb, pullup, pulldown

After reading the USB spec I am not able to understand how with both a pull-up and pull-down resistors on the D+ line in case of full speed and D- line in case low speed is able to signal.

For example in case of full speed how can I find the output when the D+ line goes high or low? Won't it become a voltage divider and simply provide a constant level?

Picture below for reference:

[image]

Comment: This may help a little: http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_6.htm

Comment: `D+` is directly connected to `Dout`, so when `D+` goes high or low, so does `Dout`.

Answer (score 1):

When D+ is open, this circuit is indeed  voltage divider, with the resulting voltage being 3 V.

However, when the transmitter is driving the D+ signal, it is essentially connecting this line directly to 3.3 V (for a high signal) or to ground (for a low signal). This means that one of the resistors is practically shorted out, and the voltage of D<sub>out</sub> is either 3.3 V or 0 V.

Comment: When the D+ Signal is being driven it again becomes a voltage divider with the voltage drop across the 1.5K ohm resistor, correct? Also how is the circuit analysis done when the D+ signal is driven to ground with the parallel 15K ohm resistor?

Comment: The driver can be seen as a 0 ohms (or a very small) resistor to VCC or ground, so the voltage divider changes.